# Xcode 7 unable to access launch image programmatically from the set of images called "Brand Assets"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just just migrated my launch images to assets with Xcode 7. My app was not using assets before.
Xcode created an image catalog with AppIcon set an another set called "Brand Assets" with all my default images and that work just great.
But, now I want to access the launch image programmaticaly.

I tried `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Brand Assets"]` and it does not work

And here is what xcode generated as images

/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700-568h@2x.png,
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png,
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700-Landscape~ipad.png,
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png,
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700-Portrait~ipad.png,
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../my.app/Brand Assets-700@2x.png,

I guess I can use 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Brand Assets-700@2x.png"] for iPhone or the other generated names for iPad Portrait or Landscape

Is there a more safe way to obtain the generated launch screen so I can use it in my code ?

Someone experimented this ?

Note: My app support ios7

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the name of the image set, not the name of the asset. But you really shouldn't attempt to load a launch image using `UIImage` because the algorithm to load an image using `imageNamed:` doesn't match how launch image assets are setup.

Comment: I need to use launch image to add an activity indicator while my data is downloading, what can I do then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the open the Assets.xcassets to open the xcode assets & then you can use the name as follows:

[image]

Select the Assets.xcasssets from Project navigator,then all assets that you have added will be displayed, so in the example below you can use the asset as follows:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"report"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I have Images.xcasset and inside I have my "Brand Assets" with all the launch images so I did what you say and the image is not loaded, is there a special case with launch images?

Comment: No, it should have worked,can you upload your screen shot of assets & code sample?

Comment: My launch image is good but when I do [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brand Assets"] the image is not loaded Brand Assets it's the name that xcode gived to my launch images

Comment: I think I understand the issue: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image set"] work great for all image assets but for AppIcon and LaunchImage sets, it could not work as the naming convention is different as the generated images are not 1x 2x or 3x.

Comment: ok you were using the launch images for image assets, you can not use appicon & launch image in app, appicon is used to change application icon & launch images loads the launch images in launch screen

Comment: Thanks for the answer